# onload event on document.body behaving strange

Tags: javascript, events, dom, onload

I am using firefox 4.0 and when i use load event on the body element it behaves strange. i have tried some things and some work and some dont.
the first is like this

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var load = function(){
alert("body loaded");      //alert not displayed
};
document.body.addEventListener("load",load,false);
</script>
</head>
<body >
</body>
</html>
```

now this doesnt work 
now i tried this

```
     html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var load = function(){
    alert("body loaded");      //alert displayed
    };
    </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="load()">
    </body>
    </html>
```

this works 
now i tried this

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var load = function(){
alert("body loaded");       //alert not displayed
};
document.body.onload=load;
</script>
</head>
<body >
</body>
</html>
```

this doesnt work.
Whats wrong?

as response to Doug D i tried this

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var load = function(){
alert("body loaded");       //alert not displayed
};
document.body.onload=load;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

this doesnt work either neither does this work

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var load = function(){
alert("body loaded");       //alert not displayed
};
document.body.onload=load;
</script>
</html>
```

in the last attempt the `body has finished loading`and in the second last attempt `body is being loaded`. but this does not work still

Comment: There is no `body.onload`. There is, however `<body onload="handler()">`.

Comment: @Matt McDonald: arent these same? and what about using addEventListner on body? that didnt work too

Answer (score 1):

The `body` can't be accessed in the head until it has been loaded. Your second technique of using the onload attribute is correct. Alternately, I would recommend using jQuery with

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    alert("body loaded");
});
```

It is cross-browser compatible. Without jQuery you would need to deal with DOM event differences between IE and others.

Comment: In your first example, the event listener needs to be added to the document, not document.body.

Comment: D: i am attaching the load event to the body not the document so it needs to be added to document.body

Comment: Try document.addEventListener("load",load,false); (but not on IE)

Comment: @Doug Domeny: Update -- IE 9 now supports `addEventListener`.